# Stretch sidebar to 100% height

Tags: html, css, height, stretch

How do I stretch a sidebar div to 100% height without the parent height to be specified?

The reason the parent height can't be used is because the content area is dynamic.Using height will just clip my div content.

Here is what I did:

```
.left {
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
  background: green;
  padding-right:5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.right {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  background: yellow;
  height:100%;/*doesn't stretch*/
}
```

http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/mJEKZe

Comment: You can't. The `height` percentage are relative to the parent's `height`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the parent of left and right to position:relative,and set the right element to position absolute.

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    ...
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    background: yellow;
}
.left {
    width: 70%;
    background: green;
    padding-right:5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zhouxiaoping/jnde5eod/
you may modify it in details, I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have this jQuery solution for what you need. Getting the `outerHeight` of the left container and passing it as a CSS `height` for the right container.

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8wc6Lxt/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mainH = $('.left').outerHeight();

    $('.right').css("height" , mainH);
});
```

Hope this helps :) Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

I recommend seeing if any of these tricks work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If `.left` and `.right` are both child elements of a content div and their heights are set to 100% or any percentage then their heights will be equal no matter what the parent element's height is. It can be dynamic without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you could use `position: fixed`:

```
.right {
    background: yellow;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 30%; /* Was this supposed to be width: 30%? (right was defined twice) */
}
```